# Camel - set value in processor but is null outside processor

Tags: java, apache-camel

I'm trying to populate an ApplicationScoped POJO inside an an Apache Camel processor. I set, and check that the values are set, inside a processor, but outside, the processor the POJO is null.

```
//Get login token from our service      
    from(inputEndpoint).routeId("getAuthToken").streamCaching()
        .process(new Processor() {

            @Override
            public void process(Exchange arg) throws Exception {
                arg.getOut().setBody(new LoginVM("admin", "admin", true));

            }
        })
    .marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, true)
    .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("POST"))
    .setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, constant("application/json"))
    .to("http://localhost:8080/api/authenticate")
    .log("RESULT FROM AUTH ENDPOINT IS ${body}") // CORRECT RESULT
    .unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, AuthToken.class)
    .process(new Processor() {

        @Override
        public void process(Exchange exch) throws Exception {               
            authToken=exch.getIn().getBody(AuthToken.class);
            System.out.println("VALUE IS " + authToken.getId_token()); // CORRECT RESULT - SET VALUE OF authToken
            exch.getOut().setBody(authToken);
        }
    })
    .log("Bearer is :" + authToken.getId_token()) //TODO - this shouldnt be null!
```

My AuthToken POJO is

```
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.inject.Singleton;


@Singleton
public class AuthToken {

    String id_token;

    public String getId_token() {
        return id_token;
    }

    public void setId_token(String id_token) {
        this.id_token = id_token;
        System.out.println("The value in AuthToken is " + this.id_token);
    }

}
```

I cannot see why it loses its value.

Answer (score 0):

This code

`.log("Bearer is :" + authToken.getId_token())`

Is only executed once when Camel is starting and creates the route.

If you want to do dynamic logging, then use the simple language which is baked in the log EIP: http://camel.apache.org/simple

From simple you can call methods on the message body to be logged

`.log("xxx ${body.getId_token()}");`

Comment: Simple, seems to be not so simple. If I use  `.log("test is :" + simple(test))` or  `.log("Using simple :   ${type:my.fqn.MyRoutes.test}") ` the result is still null, even though I set the value previously in a Processor.

Comment: Im not trying to get a value that is in the exchange, but rather from the class that extends from  `RouteBuilder `.